# Tic Tac Toe Tie Swift 3

Tags: ios, swift

I'm currently following The Swift Guy's tutorial for a Tic Tac Toe game (https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=rD3uqeLdal8) and I'm really stuck on a problem with the code.

While the game determines if there's a draw (tie), sometimes when all the spaces are taken on the board and there's a win, the game says it's a tie when really, the cross or nought should've won. It doesn't register the win. If anyone could help me with this that'd be appreciated.

```
var activePlayer = 1 //Cross
var gameState = [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0]

let winningCombinations = [[0, 1, 2], [3, 4, 5], [6, 7, 8], [0, 3, 6], [1, 4, 7], [2, 5, 8], [0, 4, 8], [2, 4, 6]]
var gameIsActive = true


@IBOutlet weak var label: UILabel!



@IBAction func action(_ sender: AnyObject)
{
    if (gameState[sender.tag-1] == 0 && gameIsActive == true)
    {
        gameState[sender.tag-1] = activePlayer

        if (activePlayer == 1)
        {
            sender.setImage(UIImage(named: "Cross.png"), for: UIControlState())
            activePlayer = 2
        }
        else
        {
            sender.setImage(UIImage(named: "Nought.png"), for: UIControlState())
            activePlayer = 1
        }
    }

    for combination in winningCombinations
    {
        if gameState[combination[0]] != 0 && gameState[combination[0]] == gameState[combination[1]] && gameState[combination[1]] == gameState[combination[2]]
        {
            gameIsActive = false

            if gameState[combination[0]] == 1
            {
                label.text = "CROSS HAS WON!"
            }
            else
            {
                label.text = "NOUGHT HAS WON!"
            }

            playAgainButton.isHidden = false
            label.isHidden = false
        }
    }

    gameIsActive = false

    for i in gameState
    {
        if i == 0
        {
            gameIsActive = true
            break
        }
    }

    if gameIsActive == false
    {

            label.text = "IT WAS A DRAW"
            label.isHidden = false
            playAgainButton.isHidden = false
        }

}
```

[image]

Comment: Delete `gameIsActive = false` before `for i in gameState`

Comment: @CleverError Unfortunately it's still saying it's a draw when cross wins.

Comment: i guess it's my night for stupid questions. I see where your winningCombinations array is zero-base (as one would expect). But I also see you are decrementing 1 from the tag property. Is that the issue?

Comment: @dfd No, that doesn't seem to be the issue as when I increment rather than decrement, I get an error.

Answer (score 0):

I find your code for the winning detection a bit overload, because of the array of winning combinations.
I've the same task for my iOS course at my university and came up with this.
My gamefields are all set to 0
Player1 is = X
Player2 is = O

Maybe it will help some ppl, when they find this post.

```
func checkRow(theRow: Int) -> String {
    if gameField[theRow][0] != "0" {
        let checkThisPlayer: String = gameField[theRow][0]
        if gameField[theRow][1] == checkThisPlayer &&
            gameField[theRow][2]  == checkThisPlayer {
            return checkThisPlayer
        }
    }
    return "0"
}

func checkColumn(theColumn: Int) -> String {
    if gameField[0][theColumn] != "0" {
        let checkThisPlayer: String = gameField[0][theColumn]
        if gameField[1][theColumn] == checkThisPlayer &&
            gameField[2][theColumn]  == checkThisPlayer {
            return checkThisPlayer
        }
    }
    return "0"
}

func checkDiagonal() -> String {
    if gameField[0][0] != "0" {
        let checkThisPlayer: String = gameField[0][0]
        if gameField[1][1] == checkThisPlayer &&
            gameField[2][2]  == checkThisPlayer {
            return checkThisPlayer
        }
    } else if gameField[0][2] != "0" {
        let checkThisPlayer: String = gameField[0][2]
        if gameField[1][1] == checkThisPlayer &&
            gameField[2][0]  == checkThisPlayer {
            return checkThisPlayer
        }
    }
    return "0"
}

func playerWon() -> String {
    //TODO Implement Draw check
    var winner: String = "0"
    for index in 0...gameField.count - 1 {
        winner = checkRow(theRow: index)
        if (winner != "0") {
            break
        }
        winner = checkColumn(theColumn: index)
        if (winner != "0") {
            break
        }
    }
    if winner == "0" {
        winner = checkDiagonal()
    }
    return winner
}
```